# Is there any way to block files being committed to SVN repository

Tags: svn, version-control

Today I came across a problem where someone had accidentally committed a proj.user file to the SVN repository. When i came to update, it obviously caused issues.

It got me wondering if there was any way that you can block certain file extensions to be committed to the repository.

I do realise there is an ignore list but as far as I am aware this still relies on the person to add the files to ignore list. Ideally I would like to control this centrally so that the repository rather than the person has control.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, in general there are two ways. Either create commit-hooks (which is probably not what you want to do), or, more easily, add the svn:ignore property to your directory. Since properties are maintained along with the project, this will effect everyone. For instance, to ignore `*.user` files, you could add this to the directory where they would appear:

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*.user' .
```

Then commit your change as usual. From now on, *.user files in that directory will no longer participate in svn commands such as stat, update, commit and so forth. You do have to add the property to each directory that requires an ignore field, however. It does not automatically act recursively on your project tree. If, for any reason, you do want to update an ignored file, you would pass the `--no-ignores` flag to the command.

Comment: Will this actually keep it from being explicitly `$ svn add`'ed?

Comment: No, if you specifically add it, it will be added, but updates to it will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly add a subversion pre-commit hook to prevent people commiting them. This has the advantage of being server side, rather than a per client setting.

Comment: Subversion properties are also managed with the project, so they have the benefit of being revisioned as well as being maintained on the server :) plus they don't require coding.

Comment: They do, but they are also more of a pain to setup when you have a lot of projects/directories.. swings and roundabouts and all that :)

Comment: I absolutely agree if you're an experienced Subversion administrator, but if you're asking this question here, I think the extra work of adding the svn:ignore property to multiple project dirs might be the better choice :)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this:

> Will this actually keep it from being
>   explicitly $ svn add'ed? – sirlancelot
>   Jan 6 '09 at 18:14
>
> No, if you specifically add it, it
>   will be added, but updates to it will
>   be ignored. – Jason Coco Jan 6 '09 at
>   20:08

I believe you can't do this playing with svn:ignore props. As per svnbook 1.5 manual:

> "Subversion's support for ignorable
>   file patterns extends only to the
>   one-time process of adding unversioned
>   files and directories to version
>   control. Once an object is under
>   Subversion's control, the ignore
>   pattern mechanisms no longer apply to
>   it. In other words, don't expect
>   Subversion to avoid committing changes
>   you've made to a versioned file simply
>   because that file's name matches an
>   ignore pattern—Subversion always
>   notices all of its versioned objects."

Comment: Plus 1, as this is an important distinction between svn and git, as git will allow you add a file to the repo and not track changes, for ex., audio or graphic files.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*.user' .
```

In order to use the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add on the server side a ignore list ? I think it's not directly possible but you can analyze the files in the pre-commit hook (see : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1) and reject completly the commit if the name/pattern is incorrect ?

Answer (score 0):

In SVN, you add files to the repository manually. Thus it does not make sense to have a file extension block list. You can use svn ignore to ignore specific files, but again, you are meant to manually add and remove files from the repository.

See also [How do you remove a file from being version controlled without deleting the file in subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210933/how-do-you-remove-a-file-from-being-version-controlled-without-deleting-the-file)

Comment: svn doesn't actually have an ignore command... so svn ignore will simply result in an error.

Comment: svn:ignore is not a command, it's a property: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3) property.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the [ignore property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3) you can also use the "[global-ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.3.2)" run time configuration option to do this globally. Follow the links for more info. I think the global-ignore feature is what you might be looking for.

Comment: The problem with the global-ignore setting is that it's per-client. If there's a project rule that *.user files shouldn't be revisioned but some build process or whatever generates them within controlled directories, you would have to get everyone to update their configurations manually.